# Primality test for numbers of the form $N=2 \cdot 6^n-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, primality-test

Can someone provide counterexample, if one exists, to the claim given below?

Inspired by [Lucas-Lehmer primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test) I have formulated the following claim:

> Let $P_m(x)=2^{-m}\cdot((x-\sqrt{x^2-4})^m+(x+\sqrt{x^2-4})^m)$ . Let $N= 2 \cdot 6^{n}-1 $ where $n\ge3$ . Let $S_i=S_{i-1}^6-6S_{i-1}^4+9S_{i-1}^2-2$ with $S_0=P_{18}(5)$ . Then, if $S_{n-2} \equiv 0 \pmod{N}$ then $N$ is prime .

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdizEOwjAQBHs_I9UZLgIbEUU67gmkcU-BMbKlxLYSC8TvuYaGamdXO5lPpCa2u-GWe0PKCdYy-xjuny2GF5gRDZ4PVpPybWVD75jmAMIXzr1Fx9fygD9pEMeJg5Mmee7ZiJ6e4JiPWNeUG3QSS-j0r_qy1LKlJpOmL-uELQo=&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

Note that $P_m(x)=2T_m \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$, where $T_m(x)$ is mth [Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#First_kind). Also , note that $S_i=P_6(S_{i-1})$ .

I was searching for counterexample using the following PARI/GP code:

```
CE261(n1,n2)=
{
for(n=n1,n2,
N=2*6^n-1;
S=2*polchebyshev(18,1,5/2);
ctr=1;
while(ctr<=n-2,
S=Mod(2*polchebyshev(6,1,S/2),N);
ctr+=1);
if(S==0 && !ispseudoprime(N),print("n="n)))
}
```

I have tested this claim for all $n$ up to $10000$ and there were no counterexamples.

Python script that implements this test can be found [here](https://github.com/PedjaTerzic/T261).

**EDIT**

An Android app that implements this test can be found [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07YZMPRSV).

Comment: As written, your $S_i$ does not appear to depend on the Chebyshev polynomial (except in a trivial way: by using the single value $P_{18}(5)$).

Comment: @MeesdeVries $S_i=P_6(S_{i-1})$

Comment: Why don't you explain how you got those particular constants for the recurrence relation between $S_i$ and $S_{i-1}$ ? It looks as if you didn't want to tell it all.

Comment: I noticed that your description of $S_i=P_6(S_{i-1})$ does NOT match your PARI/GP code  $S_i=P_6(S_{i-1})\  \%\ N.$